# Git deleted all my files

Tags: git

I just ran `git clean -df` in my home directory and all of my files were removed. Could anyone explain this problem? I think I accidentally committed my home directory a couple years back and this caused it to roll back to a later version? But how would I of committed it if there was no place to push it to.

Update: I found out that I created the project in the home directory.

Comment: Is there an implied "how do I recover my files?" question here? Or are you simply curious about what happened?

Comment: @meagar, no I just want to know what occured so I can learn from the experience. I know that the files are gone.

Comment: That depends on if you *ever* tracked them. There is a very contrived way that the files could be recoverable, if you had previously added and committed them, and then soft-reset to an earlier state before running `git clean`, but this seems very unlikely.

Comment: *But how would I of committed it if there was no place to push it to.* demonstrates a **fundamental** lack of comprehension of what **Distributed** Version Control systems do and how they work.

Comment: nope they were never committed. I'm trying to see if the directory was every tracked. Do you know of a command for this?

Comment: @JarrodRoberson That is correct, I've never used git before. If I was experience, I don't believe I would be having this problem.

Comment: This question doesn't require a downvote, just because it depicts a silly action someone should not have done. (unless u r down voting for off topic for not being related with programming ) Rather it's a good question for the lesson.

Comment: @Vishwanath thank you for your help. Just a quick question. How do I check which repo the current directory is pushed to?

Comment: @AzureWorld I am not sure if you understand distributed part of git Do check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_revision_control for more information. Git's distribution means every repository is a server. Now if you are asking how do u check which remote server your local respository is connected to then you can use `git config --get remote.origin.url` that will work only in case of when you have ur local respository tracked remotely.

Comment: Alternativly `git remote -v` will give a better human readable output about any remotes registered in the repository. @Vishwanath FYI

Answer (score 3):

> ... caused it to roll back to a later version?

That's not what `git clean` does. It simply removes any files that aren't currently tracked by Git. It does not change tracked files which contain modifications.

> But how would I of committed it if there was no place to push it to.

That has nothing to do with how Git works. You do not need to *push* anything anywhere in order to initialize a repo and begin committing things to it.

If you initialize a repository in a directory that has files, that's fine. Now your repository has 0 tracked files, and every file that was already present is an *untracked* file.

You then told Git to *delete* all untracked files, and confirmed that you did indeed want Git to do this destructive action with the `-f` flag. To make it worse, you used `-d` to tell Git to recursively descend into directories and delete any untracked files it finds there too.

Comment: This is frightening. I'm not OP. but is there any way to get those files back.. Just curious...

Comment: @Vishwanath No, they're gone, baring some other form of backup. This is no more frightening than knowing that `rm -rf *` exists. Yes, if you do silly things, you can delete all your files. The answer is not to do those things.

Comment: not knowing what you are doing is very frightening, that is the lesson, not that there is something wrong with `git`.

Answer (score 2):

See the [documentation for `git clean`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean)

> -d
>   Remove untracked directories in addition to untracked files. If an untracked directory is managed by a different Git repository, it is not removed by default. Use -f option twice if you really want to remove such a directory.
>
> -f
>   --force
>   If the Git configuration variable clean.requireForce is not set to false, git clean will refuse to run unless given -f, -n or -i.

Basically you told git to remove all files in the current directory that it didn't know about

Comment: you have not see `git status`?